# Shutdown button in XFCE restarts computer

Tags: arch-linux, boot, xfce

To turn off my Arch Linux laptop, I click the power button which brings up a panel where I can click "Shutdown" (among "reboot", "log off", etc).

When I do, my computer shuts down and restarts after a couple of seconds of appearing off, including the HDD lights.

When I open the terminal and type `shutdown -h now` It turns off completely and does not reboot.

Is there a config file to fix this in XFCE?